# Data structure for working with rows and columns

Tags: python, data-structures

I have data grabbed to Python that is in table form:

```
Name  Sport   Score  
John  Golf    100
Jill  Rugby   55
John  Hockey  100
Bob   Golf    45
```

How can I format this table in Python that would make it easy to sort or group items. For example, if I wanted to see all the names of people that played Golf or all of the people that scored 100 on any sport. Or all of the data for just John.

Comment: Please clarify; is your problem *storing* this data, or *printing* this data?

Comment: ordered dictionary or named tuple may serve your purpose

Comment: @JesseTG The data will be stored and then written to excel

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Everyone says that dictionaries are inherently unordered?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use pandas ?

Comment: @Prof That actually depends on the dictionary's implementation.  Python's is not ordered, but it does have ordered ones available (and other language's dictionaries may be).

Comment: @Prof, yes, dictionaries are unordered. But the ordered dictionary is a special data structure in collections module on top of dictionary.

Comment: @Moritz What should I know about Pandas

Comment: you can read in table like data, group, sort etc. and save to excel. Furthermore, pandas is written in C and therefore quite fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas`' `DataFrame` will be the way to go:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Jill', 'John', 'Bob'], 
                   'Sport' : ['Golf', 'Rugby', 'Hockey', 'Golf'],
                   'Score': [100, 50, 100, 45]}) 

# the names of people that played Golf

df[df['Sport'] == 'Golf']['Name'].unique()
>> ['John' 'Bob']

# all of the people that scored 100 on any sport.

df[df['Score'] == 100]['Name'].unique()
>> ['John']

# all of the data for just John.
df[df['Name'] == 'John']
>>    Name  Score   Sport
   0  John    100    Golf
   2  John    100  Hockey
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` and `filter` with `namedtuple`s and `lambda`s can be used for this task.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

# Create a named tuple to store the rows
Row = namedtuple('Row', ('name', 'sport', 'score'))

data = '''Name  Sport   Score  
          John  Golf    100
          Jill  Rugby   55
          John  Hockey  100
          Bob   Golf    45'''

# Read the data, skip the first line
lines = data.splitlines()[1:]
rows = []
for line in lines:
    name, sport, score = line.strip().split()
    rows.append(Row(name, sport, int(score)))

# People that played Golf
golf_filter = lambda row: row.sport == 'Golf'
golf_players = filter(golf_filter, rows)

# People that scored 100 on any sport
score_filter = lambda row: row.score == 100
scorers = filter(score_filter, rows)

# People named John
john_filter = lambda row: row.name == 'John'
john_data = filter(john_filter, rows)

# If you want a specific column than you can map the data
# Names of golf players
get_name = lambda row: row.name
golf_players_names = map(get_name, golf_players)
```

Results:

```
>>> golf_players
[Row(name='John', sport='Golf', score=100),
 Row(name='Bob', sport='Golf', score=45)]

>>> john_data
[Row(name='John', sport='Golf', score=100),
 Row(name='John', sport='Hockey', score=100)]

>>> scorers
[Row(name='John', sport='Golf', score=100),
 Row(name='John', sport='Hockey', score=100)]

>>> golf_players_names
['John', 'Bob']
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
yourDS={"name":["John","Jill","John","Bob"],
    "sport":["Golf","Rugby","Hockey","Golf"],
    "score":[100,55,100,45]
}
```

This should hold the relation of each entry as list are ordered.

To avoid the effect of duplicate element in a list, first make a new `set` from the list.

For your expected query, you can do something like that.

```
for index,value in enumerate(yourDS["score"]):
    if value=="x":
        print yourDS["name"][index]
```

It's better to use a `list` to store the result and make it a `set`, to avoid some cases for example, if a man has score of `x` in two different games.

Comment: But how would I "query" it, for example, how would I get all of the people that have score x

Answer (score -1):

You can create list of lists. each row will be a list inside a list.

```
lst1=[['John','Golf',100],['Jill','Rugby',55],['John','Hockey',100],['Bob','Golf',45]]
lst100=[]
for lst in lst1:
    if lst[2]==100:
        lst100.append(lst)
print lst100
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to *retrieve information* based on your data, I'd go with SQL.  It's well-suited to answering questions like these:

> ...to see all the names of people that played Golf...
>
> ...all of the people that scored 100 on any sport...
>
> ...all of the data for just John.

The most popular database language these days is SQL, and as it happens Python actually has built-in support for it through the [`sqlite3` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

SQL, while not a monumental task to learn, is beyond the scope of this answer.  To learn that, I'd recommend checking out [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/learn-sql), [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/), or [SQLZOO](http://sqlzoo.net/) (they're all interactive).

Or, if you just want to read it in and write it out without caring about what it actually means, consider using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which is also built-in.

Comment: Yes I thought this all sounds perfect for SQL but as I want to develop this code for users that may not have SQL installed (may even push this as .exe with dependancies bundled in) how would that affect things?

Comment: Actually, `sqlite3` is bundled with python, so it's already there.  Part of the standard library.